# Transcrypt: Inherit from a JS prototype?

Tags: transcrypt

Is there any way to inherit a Transcrypt class from a JS prototype?  I've got a JS object type that has a fairly heavy set of functionality I need to preserve, but I'd like to extend it with a lot of the nice affordances in a Transcrypt class (in particular, I'd like to supplement clunky JS math functions with Transcript operator overloads).

I've tried the obvious:

```
class MyClass (MyJSClass):
    ....
```

But that doesn't work because the JS class doesn't have Transcrypt's "magic methods".

I've also tried adding methods to the JS prototype:

```
def add_repr(orig):
    def v_repr(self):
        return "(inherited JS Object)"
    orig.prototype.__repr__ = v_repr

add_repr(MyJSClass)

print (__new__(MyJSClass()))
```

but in that case the the `repr` never gets called because Transcrypt is looking for other magic methods or identifiers and doesn't find them so it doesn't go looking for `repr`

Has anybody worked out a method for either retroactively turning a JS prototype into a Transcrypt class or for inheriting a Transcrypt class from a JS prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, Transcrypt classes differ internally from JavaScript classes, due to the support for multiple inheritance and bound function assignment.

A clean solution is to make a Transcrypt facade class, that encapsulates the corresponding JavaScript class.

So to make Transcrypt class `Y_tr` (and other classes) inherit from JavaScript class `X_js`, define a Transcrypt class `X_tr` with an object `x_js` of class `X_js` as it's sole attribute (created by `X_tr.__init__`). You can then have `Y_tr` inherit from `X_tr` instead of from `X_js`.

Say `X_js` has methods `m_a` and `m_b`, then give `X_tr` also methods by that name. Method `X_tr.m_a` just calls `x_js.m_a` and `X_tr.m_b` just calls `x_js.m_b`, returning the respective results.

Attributes of `x_js` can be accessed via properties of `X_tr` having the same name.

Note that `X_tr` and `Y_tr` can be instantiated without using `__new__`, since `self.x_js = __new__ (X_js ())`is done in `X_tr.__init__`.

Comment: OK, so a manual facade is the only way to go.  Got it. Thanks.